# What is meant by "function on the unit cube"?

Tags: functions, neural-networks

From [these](https://users.wpi.edu/%7Emsarkis/BrownBag/Elisa1.pdf) slides (emphasis mine):

> We proved that any continuous **function on the unit cube** can
> be uniformly approximated by a one layer network with an
> arbitrary continuous sigmoidal nonlinearity.

What does the author mean by "function on the unit cube"?

Comment: It means any (real) function which has the unit cube as its domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at slide 8: $I_n=[0,1]^n$ is the n-dimensional *unit cube*.

*Functions on the unit cube* means functions with $I_n$ as its [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function).

Comment: My intuition was that the restraint was to the *codomain* of the function, since the codomain of sigmoids is $]0, 1[^n$. Thank you!

Comment: @SaucyGoat: You are welcome. It is worth noticing that usually these kinds of questions can be solved by simply "reading ahead" until one sees where the relevant concepts/definitions are used.

Comment: Agreed. I was really just skimming through the slides to find the takeaways from Cybenko's Theorem, and even reading "$C(I_n)$ space of continuous functions on $I_n$" didn't make it click for me :)

Answer (score 2):

The domain of the function is the unit cube, $[0,1]^n$.